# re-maximize a minimized Gui

Tags: autohotkey

Is it possible to prevent a Gui to minimize on a WIN+D shortcut ?

One way of doing it would be to check from time to time if the Gui element is minimized and re-maximize it. But I don't know how to do that.

A very simple example script I'm working with as a reference

```
Gui +LastFound -Caption +ToolWindow -SysMenu

Gui, Color, 000000

Gui, Font, FF0000
Gui, Font, s12
Gui, Add, Text, vTxt cWhite, XXXXX YYYYY  ; XX & YY serve to auto-size the window.

WinSet, TransColor, 0
SetTimer, UpdateOSD, 200

Gosub, UpdateOSD  ; Make the first update immediate rather than waiting for the timer.
Gui, Show, x10 y10, NoActivate; NoActivate avoids deactivating the currently active window.
return

UpdateOSD:
MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
GuiControl,, Txt, X %MouseX%, Y %MouseY%
return
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Related: [Keep window maximized with AutoHotkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877213/keep-window-maximized-with-autohotkey)

Answer (score 0):

You can use context sensitivity to find out which GUI you have active and then write a standard button press shortcut, that then leads nowhere

```
#IfWinActive Untitled - Notepad
  #d::
    MsgBox , , Winkey + D pressed, You were inside a new untitled notepad and pressed Windows key + D but I stopped all actions
   ; Do nothing now
  return
#IfWinActive
```

I just tested it... I keyed it to simple notepad, works for me.

[Added a screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiVdx.png)